Admob ads auto add Foreground Services permission in app bundle which causes problems in Google Play
Google Play console informed me I need to use latest SDK to publish new app bundles I did so but the latest bundle also required me to update the admob ads sdk to latest version which then caused a serious problem.
  implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.3.0")

When I added the dependency for latest SDK it automatically ads FOREGROUND SERVICES permission out of nowhere in google play console while looking at app bundle published. I am supposed to explain this in play console why I am using this permission but its just admob doing it. There is supposed to be also a video explaining the use of this permission. What am I supposed to do? I do not know where and why does admob add these permissions?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic/272167
